# How can i use vue-virtual-scroller with vue use useInfiniteScroll?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, infinite-scroll, vue-composition-api, vueuse

I'm currently working on implementing infinite scroll in a Vue application using the `useInfiniteScroll` function from `@vueuse/core`. However, I'm facing an issue with binding the `ref` to the scrollable element.

The infinite scroll functionality is not working as expected. The `useInfiniteScroll` callback function is not triggered when scrolling near the bottom of the element. I am using [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/tree/master) for virtual list.

I have followed the steps mentioned in the documentation and made sure that:

- The `ref` is correctly defined using the `ref()` function in my JavaScript code.
- The `ref` is assigned to the scrollable element within the `DynamicScroller.e-solution-list__body` component, which I'm using in my template.

Here's my code:

```
<template lang="pug">
DynamicScroller.e-solution-list__body(:items="items" :min-item-size="54" v-if="items.length && !solutionTable.loading" :emit-update="true" ref="scroller")
        template(#default="{ item, index, active }")
          DynamicScrollerItem(:item="item" :active="active" :data-index="index")
            .e-solution-list__row(:key="item.id" :class="{ 'e-solution-list__row--expanded': isExpanded(item.id), 'e-solution-list__row--mobile-border': !isExpanded(item.id) || !item.tags.length }")
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { useInfiniteScroll } from '@vueuse/core'
 setup(props) {
    const columns = ref(SOLUTION_COLUMNS)
    const id = ref(props.problemId)
    const solutionTable = reactive({
      loading: false,
      loadMore: false,
      data: [],
      totalCount: 0,
      query: {
        sortBy: '-createdDate',
        skip: 0,
        limit: USE_CASE_LIMIT,
        text: '',
        popPaths: 'solutionProviderList,actors,sfCategories,sfSubCategories,sfIndustries,sfTechnologies,sfTags'
      }
    })
    const scroller = ref<HTMLElement>(null)
 //infinite scroll
    nextTick(() => {
      useInfiniteScroll(
        scroller,
        () => {
          getRelatedSolutions({
            skip: items.value.length,
            limit: USE_CASE_LIMIT,
            loadMore: true,
            isScrollTop: false,
            sortBy: sortBy.isAscending ? sortBy.key : `-${sortBy.key}`
          })
        },
        {
          distance: ITEM_HEIGHT * 2
        }
      )
    })

    
}


</script>
```

Despite following these steps, the infinite scroll functionality is not working as expected. The `useInfiniteScroll` callback function is not triggered when scrolling near the bottom of the element. I have tried the following approaches, but none of them resolved the issue:

1. Ensuring the `ref` is properly assigned within the `DynamicScroller.e-solution-list__body` component.
2. Accessing the scrollable element using `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` instead of a `ref`.
3. Wrapping the `useInfiniteScroll` call in the `$nextTick` function to ensure the DOM is updated.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue and get the infinite scroll working correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `ref`'s value is `null` before the component is mounted. You have to defer initiating the infinite scroller to [onMounted](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted):

```
import { ref, onMounted, defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  //...
  setup(props) {
    // ...
    const scroller = ref<HTMLElement>(null)
    onMounted(() => {
      useInfiniteScroll(
        scroller,
        () => {
          getRelatedSolutions({
            //...
          })
        }
      )
    })
    return { 
      //...
      scroller //  this is important if not using `<script setup>`
    }
  }
})
```

2. If you're not using `<script setup>`, your `setup` function has to return all reactive references used by `<template>` (as shown above).

---

**Important note:** I noticed your `<script>` is not a `<script setup>` ***<sup>1</sup>*** and does not have a default export. If this is due to partial copy/pasting, ignore this note. But if that's what you're using, you should either:

- wrap `setup` function in `export default { /* code here */ }`
- wrap `setup` function in `export default defineComponent({ /* code here */ })` (recommended, for typescript).

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - `<script setup>` doesn't need a default export, as it takes the contents and treats it as if it was the contents of a `setup()` function, providing the necessary boilerplate for it in the compiled code.

Comment: Thank you for your kind, detailed, helpful response. I have tried using useInfiniteScroll on onMounted but it did not trigger the function, do you have more ideas about this issue?

Comment: @eşelkeşekll, you're likely seeing some warnings/errors which are not present in your question. What you posted so far cannot be used to create a *runnable* [mcve]. Post your code on codesandbox.io and I'll have a closer look.

Comment: The project i am working on is very big and detailed, i have checked my console for errors, and encountered anything

Comment: Apart from being incomplete (missing imports and/or variable declarations) and the problems I stated in my answer, I can't spot anything else wrong in the code you posted. In general, nobody can help fix code without being able to see and/or run it.

Comment: @eşelkeşekll, you don't have to provide your entire project. But you have to provide the minimal for anyone to repro. I have no way of knowing what versions you're using, if you [installed the plugin properly](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller/blob/master/packages/vue-virtual-scroller/README.md), etc... Make sure you read and apply the *"Installation"* and *"Usage"* sections in the docs linked above. I won't be able to help further without a runnable example.

Comment: you are right, I am sorry for missing information. After inspecting the issue further, i realized i am giving the ref value to an unscrollable element. Using infinite scroll on mounted hook solved the issue. Thanks for your help!